# What's wrong with the proof using Fatou's Lemma?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation, lebesgue-integral

[Fatou's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatou%27s_lemma#Standard_statement_of_Fatou's_lemma) states that given any measure space $(\Omega,\Sigma,\mu)$ and $X\in\Sigma,$ let $(f_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of real-valued nonnegative measurable functions $f_n:X\to [0,+\infty]$ converges to $f$ point wise. 
Then 
$$\int_X f d\mu\leq \liminf \int_X f_n\,d\mu.$$

---

If we assume that $g_n$ is integrable for each $n,$ then its pointwise limit [$g$ may not be integrable](http://pointwise%20limit%20of%20integrable%20functoins).

However, what goes wrong with the 'proof' below?

> Since each $g_n$ is integrable, so 
>   $$\int_X  |g_n| \,d\mu<\infty. $$
>   Since $(|g_n|)$ is a sequence of nonnegative measurable functions, by Fatou's Lemma, we have 
>   $$\int_X |g|\,d\mu\leq \liminf \int_X |g_n|\,d\mu<\infty.$$
>   Therefore, $g$ is integrable.

Comment: Why is it true that $\liminf \int |g_n|$ is finite?

Comment: $x_n = n < \infty$ and $\liminf x_n = \infty$.

Answer (score 2):

Take $X=\mathbb{R}$ equipped with the Lebesgue Measure. Set $g_n(x)=\chi_{[-n,n]}(x)$ i.e. 
$$ g_n(x)=
\begin{cases}
1&x\in [-n,n]\\
0&x\not\in[-n,n].
\end{cases}$$
$g_n\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ for all $n$. Moreover, 
$$ \int_\mathbb{R} g_n(x)dx=2n.$$
The pointwise limit $g(x)$ exists, and is the constant $1$ function. However, if we check our bounds, we see that 
$$ \liminf_{n\to\infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \lvert g_n(x)\rvert dx=\liminf_{n\to\infty} \:2n=\infty$$
and as such provides no "bound" on $\int g(x)dx$. So, your argument was flawed because you assumed that $\liminf \int \lvert g_n\rvert<\infty$.